# How to Track Usage of salesforce by the users?

Tags: home-page-component

How to Track Usage of salesforce by the users and how the users are interacting with the system including Salesforce classic app.

I have created a controller which tracks which object and which record is being accessed by which users. But it is unable to track the reports and the classic app as both of them does not have a '**home page**' component.

Google analytics might also not helpful in this case as it uses the home page component.

Any other way round to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you have administrative report folder where you can get two important reports to help you

1)API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days
2)Users Logged in This Week

The filters can be changed on these reports and may help you .You can further customize this and change filters on these reports as per your need

Comment: This does Not help Either.
As these reports does not shows the Source of the Object/Salesforce syatme accessed.
It only shows the the application - like data loader or Eclipse. As per my undersatnding it is not possible to track the how was the object/records were used via Salesforce classic app or the Reports.

Comment: thats true !If your requirements are deep like this then no its difficult to track